# The usage of -fsanitize flag on a target with unsupported components

Tags: c++, c, gcc, clang

When compiling  with -fsanitize do i have to compile every target with it?

I have some targets which are not supported by it (assembly and C targets).

The main executable is a supported C++ file.

Will fsanitize work? or do i need to remove the unsupported files? or will it just work the parts which were compiled with the flag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation tells us that `-fsanitize` enables AddressSanitizer, providing a link to its homepage. With that, we can get our answer straight from [the FAQ](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizer):

> Q: I've built my main executable with ASan. Do I also need to build shared libraries?
>
> A: ASan will work even if you rebuild just part of your program. But you'll have to rebuild all components to detect all errors.

Although you're not building shared libraries, this answer demonstrates that not every object linked to your executable need have AddressSanitizer enabled.

Comment: Just to clarify this- sanitizer will only work for targets you compiled with it, not for the other libs.

Comment: @OrDinari: _"But you'll have to rebuild all components to detect all errors."_ :)